# Is $B_R:=\left\{(x_n)_n: \sum_{n\geq 1} |x_n|^p\leq R\right\}$ closed in $\ell^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

> Let $1\leq p<2$ and define $\ell^p:=\left\{(x_n)_n: \sum_{n\geq 1} |x_n|^p< \infty\right\}$. I want to check that for any $R>0$ $$B_R:=\left\{(x_n)_n: \sum_{n\geq 1} |x_n|^p\leq R\right\}$$is closed in $\ell^2$.

My idea was the following:

**Proof** Let me remark that $$\begin{align}B_R&:=\left\{(x_n)_n: \sum_{n\geq 1} |x_n|^p\leq R\right\} \\&=\left\{(x_n)_n:\left( \sum_{n\geq 1} |x_n|^p \right)^{1/p}\leq R^{1/p}\right\}\\&=\{x=(x_n)_n: ||x||_{\ell^p}\leq R^{1/p}\}=\bar{B}(x,R^{1/p})\end{align}$$
But we know that $\bar{B}(x,R^{1/p})$ is a closed ball in $\ell^p\subset \ell^2$ and hence it is also closed in $\ell^2$. Thus $B_R$ is closed in $\ell^2$ for all $R$

Does this work?

Comment: A quick proof for $1<p<2$: Since $\ell_p$ is reflexive the closed balls are weakly compact in $\ell^p$ and hence also in $\ell^2$ (since the the inclusion is weakly continuous). Weakly compact sets in $\ell^2$ (or any normed space) are closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, but an objection would be that it is as hard to prove that $\bar{B}(x,R^{1/p})$ is a closed ball in $\ell^p\subset \ell^2$ as the initial problem (unless of course if it is supposed to be an application or if you are explicitly allowed to use it).

Here is a direct argument: $B_R$ can be expressed as $\bigcap_{N\geqslant 1}F_N$, where
$$
F_N:=\left\{(x_n)_n\in\ell^2: \sum_{n= 1}^N |x_n|^p\leqslant R\right\}.
$$
Therefore, it suffices to shows that for each $N$, $F_N$ is closed in $\ell^2$, which follows for example from the fact that for each fixed $N$, the map $(x_n)_n\in\ell^2\mapsto \sum_{n= 1}^N |x_n|^p$ is continuous.

Comment: Ah okey I see, nice to see a second argument, we can use that $\bar B(x,R)$ is a closed ball in $\ell^p$ sorry, but I find your argument really nice!

Comment: So we only need this $F_N$ since $(x_n)_n\mapsto \sum_{n\geq 1} |x_n|^p$ is not continuous, but why?

Comment: It might even not be well-defined on $\ell^2$, for example if $x_n=n^{-1/p}$.

Comment: Ah I see thanks!